# Silverstripe: File Permissions - Only visible to owner and admins

Tags: php, security, content-management-system, silverstripe

I'm trying to alter files so they are only visible by the owner of the file, and site-wide admins.

I have tried the 'secureassets' module, and while it's good, I need to be able to secure the file itself on upload. Is there a specific function I can access to set the visibility of the file?

Comment: You mean that you cannot access the file directly through the webserver, only passed through a SilverStripe Controller when you're logged in and have the right permissions?

Comment: Hey @wmk thanks for the response. Yes, sorry, that's a more accurate description of what I'm looking for.

Comment: Afaik that's what secureassets module is made for. I didn't try it yet... you should block direct access via .htaccess on apache and tunnel all requests through the controller.